# Speed of different data structures in Python

Tags: python, performance

I have a piece of code I need to run, however, it is taking so long. I estimate it will take a minimum of 2 hours to run and at most 100 hours. As you can see, I would like to speed this up.

My code is as follows:

```
#B1
file = open("/home/1015097/Downloads/B1/tour5.txt", "r").readlines()
# This is a very large file. You can find it on http://codemasters.eng.unimelb.edu.au/bit_problems/B1.zip
# It is named tour5.txt, you can also find the question I am trying to solve there.
racers = [int(file[0].split()[0]) / float(x) for x in file[0].split()[1::]]
print("hi")
def av(race):
    race = race.split()
    j = 0
    while j != len([float(race[0]) / float(x) for x in race[1::]]):
        racers[j] = [float(race[0]) / float(x) for x in race[1::]][j] + racers[j]
        j += 1
        print(j)
    print("yay...")
for i in range(1, len(file)):
    print("yay")
    av(file[i])
print("yaaay")
a = min(racers)
del(racers[racers.index(min(racers))])
b = min(racers)
c = b-a
h = int(c)
c-=h

m = int(c * 60)
c-=m/60
s = round(c * 60 * 60)
print(str(h) + "h" + str(m) + "m" + str(s) + "s")
```

We are currently coming first in Australia for the Code Bits contest and would not like to drop our perfect score. The random print statements were so that we could tell if the code was actually running, they are essentially checkpoints. the number that is printed out is the racer number, there are at least 3000 racers, we do not know exactly.

Comment: Why are you doing two loops?

Comment: For clarity. It is easier to debug if we can add print statements and checkpoints at certain places. If we had one loop the code would be shorter but look much worse and we would have no idea if there was an infinite loop somewhere or not.

Comment: You need to figure out which loop you can get rid of. That will speed up your code tremendously.

Comment: We tested that, the main loop (not the function) is instant. We made the function nothing and it was instant. e.g. try range(1000000001) right now, it is instant. The main loop doesn't matter, it is the list comprehensions that take forever. They take an eternity and each one is done like 12 times for each race and each one has at least 3000 maybe up to 1000000 decimals in it.

Comment: That loop is basically for i in range(12).

Comment: `[float(race[0]) / float(x) for x in race[1::]]` this is a constant, why are you recalculating it *twice* at each iteration? And in general, that loop can be written as `r0 = float(race[0])``for j,o in enumerate(race[1::]):` `racers[j] += r0/float(o)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with changing:

```
while j != len([float(race[0]) / float(x) for x in race[1::]]):
    racers[j] = [float(race[0]) / float(x) for x in race[1::]][j] + racers[j]
```

into

```
while j != len(race) - 1:
    racers[j] += float(race[0]) / float(race[j])
```

Comment: Thank you. I am stupid not to notice that. That gets rid of a whole list comprehension.

Comment: is it now fast enough?

Comment: @Elodin: the point is not really the list comprehension by itself, but the fact that you were recalculating it *twice* at each iteration for no good reason. Also, whenever you see something like `len([list comprehension without if])` or `[list comprehension without if][index]` you are obviously doing something wrong, given that the first one can be calculated from the original data, and the second one just calculating the single element you need.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid loops like the plague. Vectorize everything. Use `numpy`, etc. If you have to, even look into Cython. But most importantly, *vectorize*.

The `av()` function is probably the part where your code is taking the most time (btw, it would be a good idea to profile the code at various points, figure out the most taxing process and focus on vectorizing it). Also, try to minimize the number of initializations. If you can, create an object only once and for all.

Below is how I would change up the function.

```
import numpy as np

racers = np.array(racers)

def av(race, racers):
    race = race.split()
    race_float = np.array(len([float(race[0]) / float(x) for x in race[1::]]))
    racers += race_float
    return racers
```

Also, please refrain from:

1. Using `print` for debugging. You have a built-in `logging` module. Use it.
2. Using globals. Just pass them into functions as arguments and return the new object instead of directly modifying a global object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking at numpy arrays instead of lists. Thereby you can avoid the loops and obtain close to c -speed. This problem is easily applicable to that. And by the way why not store anything in float64 or float32 so there is no conversion of datatypes. Code example not fully portable. It is a schoolwork and I should not do it for you:

```
import numpy as np
racer=np.array(racer) # Will work for 1 d lists and for 2-d lists with same lenght
racer_time=racer/time # diving a vector by a scalar is easy
```